# What is the equivalent of trunc to get a date from timestamp in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My org is in the process of transitioning from Redshift to Snowflake and I would like to ask if there is a neater way of truncating a timestamp field to extract just the date out of it as I would do it in Redshift.

Current best Snowflake query

`select cast (date_trunc('day',max(my_timestamp)) as date) from my_table`

Equivalent Redshift query

`select trunc(my_timestamp) from my_table`

Surely it shouldn't have to be this ugly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to be what you need.

```
select to_date(max(my_timestamp))  from my_table;
```

Snowflake Documentation points to the TO_DATE function see [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html)

Comment: Or even easier `max(my_timestamp)::date`

Comment: unless any of the timestamps are "not time stamps" in the variant sense of something else, at which point try_to_date should be used.

Answer (score 2):

You could just cast to date

```
select max(my_timestamp)::date
from my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake uses the Postgres `::` convention for converting values, so you could use:

```
select date_trunc('day', max(my_timestamp))::date
from my_table;
```

I don't see anything inelegant about this.

Comment: if the values are not dates it will explode.. thus making try_to_date safer, but if you know the data is all correct :: date the best. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim . . . Are there really situations where a `timestamp`in Snowflake would not convert to a date?  I see no reason to convert a timestamp to a string to convert back to a date.

Comment: A timestamp will work just fine, but it's just a column called "my_timestamp" does not make it a timestamp. There are a couple cases I've been burnt doing a ::date or the like on date, one is a bug they are fixing currently in coalesce, and the other is when a variant column with many types in it, and they will convert data before the where clause filter the bad rows out (via another column filter).

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim . . . Of course not.  The OP says:  "if there is a neater way of truncating a timestamp field to extract just the date".